# Revert applied transformationsb in pycaret

Tags: pycaret

I am using pycaret to try regression and classification.

That's why I see that it transforms the data.

In this case I want to do more transformations and also recover the data to its original form but I can't find a way.

Does anyone know how to do it?

I leave example code with the question.

```
# first I get the transformed data
s = setup(data_utilizar, target = 'Deaths', session_id = 123)
data_transformed = s.train_transformed
data=data_transformed.values

# second I make transformations to the transformed data, 
data_internal_transformded = internal_transformation(data)

# HERE IS THE QUESTION! How to transform data to its original form?
# chatgpt says the following but it doesn't work

model = create_model('lr')
untransformed_data = untransform_dataset(data_internal_transformded , model)
```